# Frequent Mouse-Down Errors

Tags: macos, bluetooth, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I'm experiencing frequent mouse-down errors.

[image]

They say *Windowserver: Warning: Program "xxxx" posted a mouse-down, blocking hardware events, but did no further mouse activity* with various apps in addition to Finder being logged, so the application in-use seems to make no difference. I will be using an application and suddenly the track-pad no longer works. This is will last for about a minute. Sometimes, the front-most window will veer suddenly to the left so that it is halfway off the screen. I will be unable to move it until the mouse-down error ends. Most of the time, I can continue to move the mouse around during these events, but I can't click on or move anything.

Also, sometimes gestures (like 4 finger push up to reveal Mission Control) will be disabled during these events, but not always. This is extremely frustrating and very disruptive to my work; please, help me figure out what is causing this.

EDIT 1:
Here is the pastebin link from the Etrecheck report: [pastebin.com/tQuPAAVq](http://pastebin.com/tQuPAAVq) 
What is "com.JWVD.cbcache.plist"? (EDIT 2: "mike" solved this question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/143135/84304).) I, also, just noticed in the screengrab I posted that the mouse-downs seem to be happening just about every eleven minutes; not sure if that's relevant or not, but it seems as though a regular process must be occurring to cause it.

EDIT 3: Days of process elimination revealed the offending app to be Numi 2. Numi 1.7.1 does not inflict the mouse-down events for me in Mt. Lion.

Comment: Could you describe your hardware? Do you use a bluetooth mouse, USB mouse, both or more than three? I've seen a trackpad or mouse in a bag or under a book stay pressed down continually. This might be easy to triage by turning off bluetooth when the issues are happening and then using one USB mouse to see if it's hardware or software causing this...

Comment: To follow up with bmike's request, please download and run [Etrecheck](http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck) and post the output on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com). Provide the pastebin link either in the OP or in a comment reply.

Comment: I'm using a Late 2012 Mac Mini Server with a 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7, 16GBs of RAM, two 250GB internal SSDs and running 10.8.5, an Apple Bluetooth Keyboard and Trackpad, an external LG monitor attached via HDMI, 6 external hard drives (4 USB 3.0, 2 Firewire), 1 USB hub, 1 firewire DVD burner, an Ooma telo, an Airport Extreme & speakers with a USB DAC. My multifunction printer is connected to the LAN via WiFi. The problem began about a week ago.

Comment: Here is the pastebin link from the Etrecheck report: http://pastebin.com/tQuPAAVq

Comment: Should I repost this or something? The problem continues.

Comment: Your trackpad is broken.