# What is "com.JWVD.cbcache.plist"?

Tags: plist, console, macos

I'm trying to solve [some](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142774/frequent-mouse-down-errors) [problems](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=19519359#post19519359) and have run across a few things in Etrecheck of which I cannot determine the origin. One such item is the Launch Daemon "com.JWVD.cbcache.plist".

Does anyone know what this is? A Google Search reveals 3 previous posts of my own Etrecheck report containing this item and two German message board threads neither of which seem to be answering this particular question.

The content of the plist is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.JWVD.cbcache</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.JWVD.cbcache</string>
    </array>
    <key>ServiceIPC</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Listener</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SockPathMode</key>
            <integer>438</integer>
            <key>SockPathName</key>
            <string>/var/run/cbcache.socket</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/cbcache.err.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/cbcache.out.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google reckons it's Notifyr - https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/notifyr-receive-ios-notifications/id873639935?mt=8

JWVD is probably the app author's initials - https://twitter.com/JWVD

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I uninstalled that within a few minutes of installing it because it refused to pair.